# What heat & fat do you use for fried mushrooms?

Tags: frying, mushrooms

I like fried mushrooms with my steak.

What techniques should I use when cooking them?

What sort of fat (if required) should I use?

What heat is suggested?

Comment: pan-fried or deep fried?

Comment: pan-fried is the intention of the question, but interpret and answer however you see fit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cook 'em on medium-high heat in butter until they're browned and crisped to my liking. I don't cover - that seems to result in soggier mushrooms than I prefer.

Comment: Also dont crowd the pan.  Too many mushrooms will also go soggy due to lots of steam being formed when water is released and evaporates.  I also usually use a small amount of oil along with the butter.

Answer (score 4):

I sauté them in olive oil over medium heat.

Answer (score 3):

Use a non-stick pan, butter, and medium heat.
I prefer fresh, sliced mushrooms rather than canned.
Allow the sides of the mushrooms to brown to your taste.

Answer (score 3):

Medium heat in olive oil, balsamic vinegar, salt and pepper

Comment: This is awesome, especially if you want a dairy-free method.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite way is to cook them on very low heat, without fat initially. Add a tiny bit of water to the skillet. The mushrooms start to produce water and shrink, then the water boils away; the whole process takes around 20-25 minutes, and the mushrooms will be around 20% their original volume at the end of it, with a very concentrated mushroom taste. When the skillet is dry once more, add butter and chopped onion, and turn the heat up a little. Once the onion starts turning golden, stir in a little smetana or creme fraiche and it is ready to serve.